# How to sync with time in custom calendar that I have made.? Like when I open my calendar it should show the current date and month

Tags: java, android, xml

[Main Activity Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tu9N.png)I have made a custom calendar with textview, So I want the calendar to show current date and month when I open the calendar...

`My calendar should open directly in the current month and show the current date, just like google calendar.

```
<TextView
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/caviardreams"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxWidth="1dp"
            android:maxHeight="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/caviardreams"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxWidth="1dp"
            android:maxHeight="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/caviardreams"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxWidth="1dp"
            android:maxHeight="1dp"/>
```

`

I expect the current date to be highlighted in the current month.

This is the java code of MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
ViewPager viewPager;
EditText txt;
Button btn;
String str;
AdView adView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    //admob app id
    MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-6376378742627184~5911477780");

    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


}

public void date(View view) {
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

            case 0: return Frag1.newInstance("Frag1, Instance 1");
            case 1: return Frag2.newInstance("Frag2, Instance 2");
            case 2: return Frag3.newInstance("Frag3, Instance 3");
            case 3: return Frag4.newInstance("Frag4, Instance 4");
            case 4: return Frag5.newInstance("Frag5, Instance 5");
            case 5: return Frag6.newInstance("Frag6, Instance 6");
            case 6: return Frag7.newInstance("Frag7, Instance 7");
            case 7: return Frag8.newInstance("Frag8, Instance 8");
            case 8: return Frag9.newInstance("Frag9, Instance 9");
            case 9: return Frag10.newInstance("Frag10, Instance 10");
            case 10: return Frag11.newInstance("Frag11, Instance 11");
            case 11: return Frag12.newInstance("Frag12, Instance 12");
            default: return Frag1.newInstance("Frag1, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 12;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    ApplicationInfo app = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
    String filePath = app.sourceDir;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.home)
    {
        // Handle the camera action
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.about)
    {
        Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this,About.class);
        startActivity(b);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_share)
    {
        Intent c = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        c.setType("*/*");
        String shareBody = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jangphong.hem.karbicalender2";
        String shareSub = "Download Karbi calendar 2019";
        c.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSub);
        c.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
        c.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(c,"Share using"));
    }
    else if (id == R.id.feedback)
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.karbidigitalresources.tk"));
        startActivity(in);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

This is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jangphong.hem.karbicalender2">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_karbi_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_karbi_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".About" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".edit_text" />
    <activity android:name=".feb" />
    <activity android:name=".march" />
    <activity android:name=".april" />
    <activity android:name=".may" />
    <activity android:name=".june" />
    <activity android:name=".july" />
    <activity android:name=".august" />
    <activity android:name=".sep" />
    <activity android:name=".oct" />
    <activity android:name=".nov" />
    <activity android:name=".dec"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: could you share java code?

Comment: Hello.. I have added my java code in my post.. Please check it and help me if possible.. Would appreciate it.. Thanks..